# Can't set renderingOrder in SCNNode from obj , works as designed with SCNShapes

Tags: scenekit, arkit

How do I load obj:

```
guard let urlOBJ = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "myOBJ", withExtension: "obj") else {NSLog("error loding obj ");return}
let assetOBJ = MDLAsset(url: urlOBJ)
let objectOBJ = assetOBJ.object(at: 0)
OBJNode = SCNNode(mdlObject: objectOBJ)
OBJNode.name = OBJNode
annotationNode.addChildNode(OBJNode)
```

How do I set it:

```
annotationNode.childNode(withName:"OBJNode", recursively: true)!.renderingOrder                                         = 1000
annotationNode.childNode(withName:"Background", recursively: true)?.geometry!.firstMaterial?.readsFromDepthBuffer                  = false
annotationNode.childNode(withName:"Background", recursively: true)?.geometry!.firstMaterial?.writesToDepthBuffer                   = false
annotationNode.childNode(withName:"Background", recursively: true)!.renderingOrder                                         = 100
```

Please don't ask me to convert hundreds of OBJs in .scn . . .

Any alternatives? Any official explanation for that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved,

that OBJ was inside two different parents and renderingOrder is not recursive.

Thanks.